# A question on Triangle Inequality in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I'm reading a textbook on Topology. We know that $(\rho,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a metric space, where
$$\rho(x,y)=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-y_i)^2}$$for any $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n),y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$. When proving that $\rho(x,z)\le \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)$, the author uses Schwarz Inequality.

I can understand the method, but I wonder if we can do it directly. We know that three non-collinear points can determine a plane. If those three points $x,y,z$ are on a single line, then of course we can apply the Triangle Inequality on $\mathbb{R}$; if they are not, then they are on a same plane, still we can apply the Triangle Inequality. Isn't it just a question on $\mathbb{R}^2$ essentially?

Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't find it myself. Is my reasoning correct? Thank you!

Comment: Nice observation! (+1)

Comment: You are correct, it is only about the frame of reference you are in! This problem can indeed be simplified to one application of the triangle inequality.

Comment: This method still leaves you with two issues: (1) Why the $\ell_2$-norm is independent of the choice of rectangular coordinates, (2) how to prove the triangle inequality in the plane (starting with the definition of $\ell_2$-norm). That's why the author is using the CS-inequality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good point! I can’t explain why the author would go through a full algebraic proof rather than using what you noticed to simplify the problem considerably. However, I can give some advice about formalizing your idea into a full proof of the triangle inequality in $\mathbb R^n$.

Your observation that

> Any three points $\vec x, \vec y, \vec z\in\mathbb R^n$ either lie on the same line or the same plane.

is equivalent to the statement

> For any $\vec x, \vec y, \vec z\in\mathbb R^n$, there exists an isometry (distance-preserving transformation) mapping all but the first three coordinates of $\vec x, \vec y,$ and $\vec z$ to zero.

This statement shouldn’t be difficult to prove using a bit of linear algebra to show that a certain system of equations has at least one solution. Once you’ve done that, the triangle inequality in $\mathbb R^n$ follows, because any triplet of points $\vec x, \vec y, \vec z$ can be reduced by isometry to points of the form $(a,b,c,0,...,0)$, at which point the triangle inequality on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^2$ can be applied.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! +1 from me. It helps me make my mind clear. I just wonder if it should be “all but the first **two** coordinates of...” : )

Comment: As noted in a comment under the question, the "isometry" part of your equivalent statement is essential and not entirely trivial to prove. The linear algebra involved in its proof seems to include some quadratic equations.

Comment: @Benny If they’re collinear, then you can get all but the first two coordinates to equal zero. If not, then all but the first 3 coordinates can equal zero.

Comment: @Benny How much linear algebra do you know? Are you familiar with the use of matrices to solve systems of linear equations?